# Flex JSON: ignore certain properties?

Tags: json, apache-flex

Is there some library for flex, that will let me:

- define properties to fully exclude from serialization
- define classes to serialize without the property names (as if they were an array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to exclude a property from serialization you can use the [Transient] meta tag.

```
[Transient]
public var someVar:String;
```

Comment: ah ok, i thought that only worked for AMF, but it seems to work for JSON too http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/issues/detail?id=110
thanks

Comment: What if the object in question is an instance of "Object" and not of any other subclass?